# Fill whitespace after floated divs in row

Tags: html, css, grid, alignment

I have 3 floated divs on the first "row", the two first divs have a height of 100px, and the third div has a height of 200px. Anything I add after the first row won't fill the whitespace created from the third div.

CSS:

```
#container {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 440px;
    margin: -5px;
}

#container div {
    background-color: gray;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 5px;
    float: left;
}

#container #widget2 {
    width: 210px;
}

#container #widget3 {
    height: 200px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="widget1">1</div>
    <div id="widget2">2</div>
    <div id="widget3">3</div>
    <div id="widget4">4</div>
    <div id="widget5">5</div>
    <div id="widget6">6</div>
    <div id="widget7">7</div>
</div>
```

widget3 somehow creates unusable space, so that widget4 to 6 are far away and it generally looks weird.

You can see what I mean here: http://jsfiddle.net/SGdG3/80/

I want the red boxes to be "pushed" up to use the white space.

Comment: You can create a container div that contains 1, 2, 4, 5, 6 then place 3 next to it.

Comment: you may need to use a plugin for that: http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: Won't ''float:right'' help? http://jsfiddle.net/SGdG3/81/

Answer (score 0):

Basically this is how Floated elements behaves. if you want to fill the space, then you have go for absolute positioning with Javascript. Here is a Beautiful JQuery plugin for your solution.